# Carved fingerboard between frets on a guitar

Tags: guitar, fretboard

I've played the electric guitar for about ten years. I've seen and tried out various kinds of necks, but today I stumbled upon a fingerboard that goes beyond my understanding.

It looked like this:

[image: Fingerboard]

My question is; Why would someone want a fingerboard carved in between the frets like this?

*"How it feels to play"* is of course a matter taste, but doesn't such a neck:

A) excessively tighten the string (increase pitch) if pressed too hard

and
B) require a completely different fingering technique?

Is this some known kind of a fingerboard, or just some random players wild tryout?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalloped_fretboard#Scalloping

Comment: See also: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/9537/6556

Comment: A former pupil used to use that pressing technique as part of vibrato.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is called a **scalloped fingerboard**. It is used by lead guitarists who do a great deal of string-bending when playing melodies. And yes, playing one effectively requires a certain technique, because if one uses too much finger pressure, the notes and chords go way out of tune.

Here is a [page at Warmoth Custom Guitar Parts](http://www.warmoth.com/Guitar/Necks/Scalloping.aspx) where they explain different kinds of scalloping.

The most famous advocate of the scalloped fingerboard is the heavy metal guitarist [Yngwie Malmsteen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yngwie_Malmsteen). For many years the Fender guitar company has made a [Yngwie Malmsteen signature model Stratocaster](http://www.fender.com/guitars/stratocaster/yngwie-malmsteen-stratocaster-scalloped-rosewood-fingerboard-vintage-white/) that comes from the factory with a scalloped fingerboard, and from time to time they have offered other models with a scalloped fingerboard as well. So yes, this is a well-established feature of certain mass-produced electric guitars.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I stand enlightened. I'll vote up as soon as I have 15 reputation :)

Comment: It really is an expert level modification - you need to be incredibly precise with the pressure you use on the string. That does allow you to be very fast (although which one is cause and which is effect may be up for debate)

Comment: I would argue that Richie Blackmore is just a BIT more famous than Yngwie Malmsteen :P